# Why is my object not being passed correctly via segue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Say I have 2 controllers, BarViewController and FooViewController.

FooViewController has an outlet to a UIImageView called imageView:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIImageView *imageView;
```

BarViewController has an outlet to a UIButton button.
BarViewController has a segue from this button to FooViewController, called BarToFooSegue (done in storyboard).

When I run the following code, and call NSLog on FooViewController.imageView.image, the result is nil, and my image won't display. Why is this the case?

```
// code in BarViewController
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"BarToFooSegue"]){
        NSURL *photoUrl = @"http://www.randurl.com/someImage"; // assume valid url
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:photoUrl]];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

        [segue.destinationViewController setImageView:imageView];
    }
}
```

I've tried setting FooViewController.imageView to strong instead of weak, but the problem remains:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
```

Running my debugger, I notice the imageView in FooViewController is updated correctly inside prepareForSegue: but then gets re-updated a few lines afterwards to some newly allocated imageView with @property image set to nil. I am not sure what part of the control flow is causing this because it happened in lines written in assembly language.

I got my code working by adding a UIImage property to FooViewController:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *myImage;
```

and changing prepareForSegue: in BarViewController to pass the image instead of the imageView:

```
// code in BarViewController
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"BarToFooSegue"]){
        NSURL *photoUrl = @"http://www.randurl.com/someImage"; // assume valid url
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:photoUrl]];

        [segue.destinationViewController setMyImage:image];
}
```

and modifying viewWillAppear: in FooViewController:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.imageView setImage:self.myImage];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `[segue.destinationViewController view];` before you set the image, this will cause the view hierarchy to be loaded and your outlets will then be set.

Comment: Is this really a good solution? A view controller's view can be unloaded at any time if memory is low, and reloaded again if necessary. Setting the `imageView` in `viewDidLoad` seems therefore to be the more robust solution.

Comment: I believe it's a pragmatic solution when used carefully.  As with any pattern, abuse and misuse are possible of course.  The situation seems to be that the imageView is a container for some decoration that the destination doesn't really care about, so adding a property to temporarily store the UIImage, and then setting it in viewDidLoad seems like an over complication for little semantic value.  The view IS going to load because you're preparing for a segue - forcing it to load slightly earlier avoids having to write glue-code.

Comment: A more interesting problem with OP's design is that loading from a URL in prepareForSegue is going to block the main thread. I wouldn't expect the destination view controller to need to load from the network, but I could see an async NSURLConnection started in prepareForSegue, with the image set in the completion block. In this case you need to be sure the view has loaded when the completion executes and forcing the view to load would be one way to do this. @scott says that iOS6 loads the view before prepareForSegue - I haven't tested this, but it would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

In `prepareForSegue` outlets aren't defined yet--they're nil. You're sending a message to nil, which is perfectly fine and therefore doesn't give you an error, but in this case it can lead to unexpected behavior. You can solve it by creating a temporary UIImage property, and set your image view to that image in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

Comment: sorry, are you saying [segue.destinationViewController setImageView:imageView]; is doing nothing because segue.destinationViewController is nil?

Comment: It feels redundant having to make a temporary UIImage property in FooViewController. Surely there must be a neater solution?

Comment: The destination view controller isn't nil, but imageView is. You can test it by logging the image view in prepareForSegue, it will return nil. And no, unfortunately, this is how it's done. In iOS 6 this is fixed, but if you need to build for iOS 5, you'll have to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @ikuragames answer if you must set the imageView.image directly.  But typically, I keep my ViewControllers' view hierarchies private.

I don't think it's ugly to add that UIImage property to Foo.  I think it's actually prettier than @ikuragames correct solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"BarToFooSegue"]){
        NSURL *photoUrl = @"http://www.randurl.com/someImage"; 
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:photoUrl]];

   
        FooViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.myImage = image;   
 }
}
```

Comment: this is the same code as my solution to this problem. I am mainly interested in why this problem occurred, and if there's a better way to get around it