# Dismissing UIWebView when returning back to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, uitableview

I have a an application that uses a UITableViewController that calls a UIViewController with a UIWebView inside.  I have everything working good except for when I click on a table cell it takes me to the UIViewController and opens up the corresponding weburl inside but when I go back to the UITableViewController it doesn't dismiss the website.  It offsets the website, so I know I'm back to the tableview but the website is still visible.  What am I missing?

WebViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
webView2.delegate = self;
webView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
NSString *urlAddress = self.magURL;
webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webURL];
[webView2 loadRequest:requestObj];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
webView2.delegate = nil;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
```

}

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}
```

TableViewController.m
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
magazineArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[magazineArray addObject:@"Joyce Meyer"];
[magazineArray addObject:@"Perry Stone"];
[magazineArray addObject:@"Robb Thompson"];
[magazineArray addObject:@"R.W. Schambach"];
[magazineArray addObject:@"T.D. Jakes"];
[magazineArray addObject:@"Reinhard Bonnke"];
[magazineArray addObject:@"Pilot"];

self.navigationItem.title = @"Magazines";

magazineURL = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[magazineURL addObject:@"http://mysolutionsmagazine.com/solutions/2013/magazine"];
[magazineURL addObject:@"http://google.com"];
[magazineURL addObject:@"http://smithmediagroup.com"];
[magazineURL addObject:@"http://smgvoices.com"];
[magazineURL addObject:@"http://facebook.com/smithmediagroup"];
[magazineURL addObject:@"http://twitter.com/smgvoices"];
[magazineURL addObject:@"http://youtube.com/smgvoices"];

MagazineURLViewController *urlController = [[MagazineURLViewController alloc] init];
urlController.urlHolder = newURLHolder;

}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
newURLHolder = [magazineURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 690, 750)];

NSURL *webURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:newURLHolder];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webURL2];

[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.view addSubview:webView];

}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Cell2"]){
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    newURLHolder = magazineURL[indexPath.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController]setMagURL:newURLHolder];

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding your webviewcontriller's view to tableviewcontroller's view as a subview. It may look like there's nothing wrong in it, I think its a strict no no from apple (iPad is an exception, because it has splitviewcontroller that you can use).

when you are adding it as a subview, your default viewcontroller methods (viewwill/didappear etc) will not be called.

either push it as a new view controller, or present it modally, and when you pop/dismiss your webview controller, everything will work as it should.

if you dont want to push or present modally, just use a webview in your tableviewController, implement the webView's delegate methods, add that as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the webview as a subview, rather push the webview:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webview animated:YES];
```

When you want to dismiss the webview:

```
[self.parentViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];]
```

Comment: This is the Warning I get and it crashes when I run it. "Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIWebView *__strong' to parameter of type 'UIViewController *'"

Answer (score 0):

It currently looks like you never call the webViewController you create UIWebView on cell select and add it to a current view. So my question is do you ever say removeFormSuperview?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Storyboards. The problem appears to be with unnecessary code in

`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

You don't have to add the web view to your current view, you need to have that code in your `@"Cell2"` view controller.

It looks like you are almost there, you are passing a URL to the next view controller in `prepareForSegue`

You should have another view controller which reads the magURL property and displays that webpage.

Something more like this in the table view controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
  newURLHolder = [magazineURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Cell2"]){
      [[segue destinationViewController] setMagURL:newURLHolder];
  }
}
```

Then in your new view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
// if webview is created in the storyboard you won't need to `init` it here. Just use [self webView]
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 690, 750)];

NSURL *webURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[self magURL]];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webURL2];

[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

Comment: This fixed it but now the webView is loading the url offset again? any ideas?

Comment: I assume you mean the webpage is displaying with offset dimensions? `[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 690, 750)]` Is it possible that you need to change these numbers? maybe something like `CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004)` (iPad size)

Comment: Thanks that fixed.  The only issue I'm having now is that the 1st time I click on my table view cell is brings up a nul value and then if I go back to tableview and then click on a cell is works.  Do you know why I am getting a nul value the 1st time?

Comment: Referencing this [overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453096/why-is-my-object-not-being-passed-correctly-via-segue), you may have to add `[segue.destinationViewController view];` to the beginning of `prepareForSegue:` If that works I'll put it in the answer. Let me know